# Web map linked to database that shows one spatial location at a time

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

I have a simple database with a record for each research project that occured on a national forest. Each project area is associated with a polygon, and there are around 200 polygons that are piled within a relatively small area. I want to create a web map (using open source software) that has a very visible database/project description components where the user can select a project record and then I would like for the record to link to a map of the study location. I can't show all project locations at once because it's too confusing given how many are overlapping.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: http://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/

Comment: I'd suggest looking at [arcgis online](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your data is structured on the back-end, or what type of system it is stored in.  For the front end though, I would suggest using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) in conjunction with the [LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider).  Leaflet is a JavaScript mapping library.  The LeafletSlider is a way to use a slider, to view temporal data.  As you move the slider, the time window changes, and data from that time window is displayed.  It is a great technique to view data like you are describing.  The LeafletSlider website has a good demo as well.